# Arrows besides bootstrap container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap container. As this is common for it, it doesn't take the hole page width, but is centered with a lot of margin on the left and right side.

What I'm trying to achieve is, that on the left and the right side (so besides the div with the `container` class, there are 2 centered arrows, left side pointing to left and right side pointing to the right.

You wonder, why I want to do that? I try to make something like a Carousel, but with pages, so when I click on the right arrow, there comes the content of the next page, clicking on the left arrow then, I get back to the other page.. I hope you know what I mean...

What I have is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drag and Drop Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container fill">
    <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable full-height">
        <div class="dz-message"><b> </b></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way without taking your elements position in consideration would be using negative margins. ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wxmn7wvw/1/))

html:

```
<div id="arrow">&larr;</div>
```

css:

```
#arrow {
 margin-left: -100px;  
}
```

Another viable way is to use `position: absolute` like this:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#left-arrow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40%;
 bottom: 40%;
 height: 10%;
 line-height: 100%;
 left: -5%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to have it working on mobile devices as well, so I don't like pixels..

Comment: @nameless you can use negative percentage

Comment: @Jonathan Argentiero This works for having it left and right, but somehow it's above the other div, can i have this centered?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it globally as Bootstrap does with the arrow in the carousel : 
Having parents containers in each side of the page, fixed to the top AND with the screen's height as fixed height (easy to do with JQuery).

```
<body>
   <div class="parentofarrow left"><div class="parrentofarrow__arrow left"></div></div>
   <div class="parentofarrow right"><div class="parrentofarrow__arrow right"></div></div>
   <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

You could have a another parent for all of them to have a different structure or anything. (in this case change position fixed to position absolute)

And in css :

```
.parentofarrow { 
   position: fixed; // or absolute to a specific parent (relative)
   top: 0px;
   // height fixed with screensheight using Jquery
   width: // as you wish;
   text-align: center; // or margin auto on arrows
}
.parentofarrow.left { left: 0px; }
.parentofarrow.right { right: 0px; }
.parentofarrow__arrow { //customize and positionning as you wish }
```

And in these parents, having a vertical and horizontal align arrow with a specific action linked to change page content as you wish.

Should be enough!

Note that this solution is not the easiest but it offers a certain modularity (change height, parent, position...).

Comment: How would I do the jquery thing then? Because now, the div container I have has the full height of the screen, using your solution it's somehow changing....

Comment: If you fixe it just one time during the page loading it shouldn't change. 

someting like : 
`$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.yourcontainer').height($(window).height());
or with maybe 
    $('.yourcontainer').css('height', value + 'px');
});`

Check the jquery doc for .height, something i'll want to use .height(true), .outerHeight() or others.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is too use the grid system.

```
<div class="container fill">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">Left</div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 main-stage">
            <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable full-height">
                <div class="dz-message"><b> </b></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Right</div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```